# Validate Email in C#

Tags: c#, email

I have validated the email but i need to check if email exists in database or not ?
For Ex:

User has entered the new record with email.
Next time he clicks on Datagridview and all the records are loaded in textboxes.
Now He updates the email.Here it should again check if email exists.If not update the same Email.

Thank you

Comment: So what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: i need to check if email exists or not.If it exists error mas should pop up else i need to update the existing email.

Comment: updating the existing email is the problem.If i try to update the same email,i get "email already exists"

Comment: Just some hints. You need to be more specific about the problem, if you want to get some answers. What is the problem (Exception text and type) where and when does it occure, what are the components involved. People here don't like guessing on unclear questions and will likely ignore it.
And don't comment on your own question, edit it to give more details.

Answer (score 0):

From the vague information you're giving I guess the following:

1. The user adds a new record to a list of address records
2. Before the record is added you're checking whether the email address is unique (which works => the record is added)
3. When the user changes the record, the email check fails

I suppose that you fail to consider the case that you're comparing the same records. Assume the following:

1. You have records A and B, which both have unique email addresses
2. User enters new record, you validate eMail address C against A and B => unique, you add record C
3. User modifies record C, you compare eMail address against *all* known records, so you compare eMail address C with A, B and C => Of course, the eMail address is already known.

You should modify your check so that the condition is: eMail address already exists if a record with the same eMail address is found and *the record is not the same as the one being edited right now*.

But again: The information you're giving is very vague - I might be far off the right track here...

Answer (score 0):

Here is **my understanding** of your question: You want to know how to test the email on the serverside before trying to commit the update/insert.

You can create a method to fire to do the update.  Just put code in this method to check the database for the existance of the email.  Here's a good example: [http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/TheBasicoperatoinofDataGrid04252007023744AM/TheBasicoperatoinofDataGrid.aspx][1]

Go look at the updategrid_UpdateCommand method - that's where he's committing the data.  Just put in a check to query the DB before committing.  If it doesn't exist, let the commit happen, if it does (and the email address does not belong to the record being updated) then show a message to the user telling them what's wrong.

Cheers,
Lance